# How can I prevent integer ambiguity when overloading operators in C++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, ambiguity

Given the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass& operator<<(long value) { return *this; }

    SomeClass& operator<<(unsigned long value) { return *this; }

    SomeClass& operator<<(float value) { return *this; }

    SomeClass& operator<<(double value) { return *this; }

    SomeClass& operator<<(long double value) { return *this; }

    SomeClass& operator<<(bool value);
    { return *this; }

    SomeClass& operator<<(const void* value);
    { return *this; }

    SomeClass& operator<<(::std::string aString) { return *this; }
};

int main() {
    SomeClass aClass;
    std::ostringstream aStream;

    aClass << 2;
    aClass << "Hello World";
    aClass << '\0';
    aClass << -2;

    aStream << 2;
    aStream << "Hello World";
    aStream << '\0';
    aStream << -2;

    return 0;
}
```

Why is `basic_ostream` able to overload `<<` with so many integer types with no problem? Yet, the compiler is giving me  ambiguous overload errors for SomeClass's << operators?

ex:

```
../OverloadTest.cpp:65: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ in ‘aClass << 2’
../OverloadTest.cpp:14: note: candidates are: SomeClass& SomeClass::operator<<(long int)   
../OverloadTest.cpp:19: note:                 SomeClass& SomeClass::operator<<(long unsigned int)
../OverloadTest.cpp:24: note:                 SomeClass& SomeClass::operator<<(float)    
../OverloadTest.cpp:29: note:                 SomeClass& SomeClass::operator<<(double)    
../OverloadTest.cpp:35: note:                 SomeClass& SomeClass::operator<<(long double)    
../OverloadTest.cpp:40: note:                 SomeClass& SomeClass::operator<<(bool)    
../OverloadTest.cpp:46: note:                 SomeClass& SomeClass::operator<<(const void*)     
../OverloadTest.cpp:51: note:                 SomeClass& SomeClass::operator<<(std::string)
```

Comment: You have some errors in the code, probably miss copy, `operator<<` for `bool` and `const void*` line end in `;` as you where declaring the operator and not implementing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add overload at least for `int` (and for completing the code for `unsigned int` too).

```
SomeClass& operator<<(int value) { return *this; }

SomeClass& operator<<(unsigned int value) { return *this; }
```

When you call: `aClass << 2;`

Literal `2` is of type `int`, there not overload that fit exactly, the compiler need to convert the number, in the conversion is where the ambiguity appear. What is better for `2`, `long` or `unsigned long` or `float` or `double` or `long double` or even `bool`, the compiler don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answer for general cases.
One can also prevent the typecasting of floats to integer (or in general) when doing operator overloading.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class C{
        int a;
    public:
        C(int p){
            a = p;
        }
        int operator+(int a){
            return a;
        }
        float operator+(float a){
            return a;
        }
        int operator+(C a){
            
            return this->a + a.a;
        }
};

int main(){
    C a(5), b(5.5);
    cout<<(a+2)<<endl;
    cout<<(a+((float)2.5))<<endl; //here float is explicitly specified
    cout<<(a+b)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For that, while calling the operator on the object, **explicitly specify the datatype of value** like float is specifically specified, to prevent type conversion and at last ambiguity in overloaded operators.